# How can I generate an UV-coating effect

Tags: cycles-render-engine

i try to get an effect on an image texture in blender like an UV-coating.

Example could be:
https://i.shgcdn.com/1d8071fc-58f9-4ed8-b1f6-4e6febb330d9/-/format/auto/-/stretch/off/-/resize/3000x/-/quality/lighter/
or
http://fourprint.pl/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/Spot-UV-Logo-MocUp-full1.jpg

I used image texture node and put it into an glossy and diffuse node. As the fac i used Frensel node but I was not able to manage to get the effect of the reflection.

I am using cycles render only.

Should be easy, but I am not able to manage it.

Thanks a million.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to play with the settings to get the exact look you want, but the base of this material is a noise texture that controls the roughness and the displacement of the material (technically the roughness should be consistent, but it gives it more contrast IMO)

[image]